# Elasticsearch Concurrent Read and write Missing document

Tags: elasticsearch, concurrency

In elasticsearch, if i am updating a document, then for few milliseconds that document is not returned from elasticsearch.
does elasticsearch lock that document from being returned while updating???

Comment: Hi, which endpoint are you using ? `index` or `update` ? or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at `index.refresh_interval` and `index.search.idle.after` index setting. You can change these parameters but consider performance degradation if you are going to perform frequent updates with decreased values of these fields

[elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings)

Comment: so is this the default behavior of elasticsearch that document can be missed for interval in which update is happening on a document???

Comment: The document will not be missed, the clients won't see the updated state of the document for this time interval

Comment: But we are seeing document is getting missed. What could be the reason for it??? can it be because of document replacement in update api??

Comment: If you update a document, the original version will be marked as deleted and a new document will be created . We are using 2.4.1, can that be the reason for document miss???